# Correct total amount with percentage in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript file that will automatically calculate total plus the percentage.At first I thought my code was correct.

javascript.js

```
  function getPayPalProcessingFee() {
     var qty = jQuery('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
     qty = parseInt(qty);

     //var cat_buttons = jQuery("input[name=cat]")
     //var current_index = cat_buttons.index(cat_buttons.find(':checked'));
     var current_index = $("input[name=cat]:checked").attr('id');

     switch (current_index){
         case 'cat-both':
            return 3*qty;
            break;
         case 'cat-aerial':
            return 1.8*qty;
            break;
         case 'cat-loto':
            return 1.8*qty;
            break;
         default:
            return 0;
     }
 }

function trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount() {
    var qty = jQuery('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    var current_val = jQuery("input[name=cat]:checked").val();

    var amount = parseInt(qty) * current_val;
    amount = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
    return amount;
}

function trainthetrainerForm_calculateFee() {
    var fee = getPayPalProcessingFee();
    return fee;
}

function trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount() {
    var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
    console.log(amount);        
            var fee = getPayPalProcessingFee();
    console.log(fee);        
            var totalamount = parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat(fee);
    console.log(totalamount);        
            totalamount = parseFloat(totalamount).toFixed(2);
    console.log(totalamount);

    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=tmp_total_amount]').val(totalamount);
}

function submitTrainthetrainerForm() {
    var qty = jQuery('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=quantity_1]').val(qty);

    var totalAmount = 0;
    var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
    var processingFee = trainthetrainerForm_calculateFee();

    totalAmount = amount + processingFee;

    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=business]').val('shana@same.org');
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount]').val(totalAmount);
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount_2]').val(processingFee);
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form').submit();
    return true;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    $(document).on('change',$("#bal_number_of_members"),function(){
        trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
    });
    jQuery("#bal_submit_btn").click(function() {
        submitTrainthetrainerForm();
    });

    trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
});
```

form.html

```
   <h2 class="contentheading" style="margin-top: 0px;">2016 “Train-The-Trainer” Workshops<br /><br /> AERIAL</h2>
 <div>
   <p>$50.00 per class/person<br />Sign up for both for $90.00</p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <form id="paypal_submit_form" https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" /> 
    <input name="upload" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
    <input name="charset" type="hidden" value="utf8" /> 
    <input name="business" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" /> 
    <input name="custom" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="amount" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="first_name" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="last_name" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="address1" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="city" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="state" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="zip" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="email" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="night_phone_b" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="address_override" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <div id="paypal_prs" style="font-size: 12px;">
        <p>
            <input id="cat-both" checked="checked" name="cat" type="radio" value="90" />
                <label for="cat-both">Both</label> 
            <input id="cat-aerial" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" />
                <label for="cat-aerial">Aerial</label> 
            <input id="cat-loto" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" />
                <label for="cat-loto">Lockout/Tagout</label>
        </p>
        <br /> Members:
        <select id="bal_number_of_members" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 3px;" name="number_of_members">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
        </select>
        <br /> Total Amount (Cost + Processing Fee): 
            <input style="width: 50px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 2px; padding-bottom: 1px; font-size: 12px;" name="tmp_total_amount" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="93" /> 
            <input id="bal_submit_btn" style="padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 12px; cursor: pointer;" type="button" value="Pay Here" /> 
            <input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="2016 Train-The-Trainer Workshops(AERIAL LIFTS &amp; LOCKOUT/TAGOUT)" /> 
            <input name="amount_1" type="hidden" value="90" /> 
            <input name="quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
            <input name="item_name_2" type="hidden" value="Processing fee" /> 
            <input name="amount_2" type="hidden" value="0" /> 
            <input name="quantity_2" type="hidden" value="1" />
    </div>
    <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/tmp_ipn.php" /> 
    <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/" /> 
    <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/index.php?view=article&amp;id=278" /> 
    <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1" />
   </form>
   </div>
  <div style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px; color: red;">
    Additional 2.9% + $0.30 processing fee will be charged with all orders paid by credit card.
   </div>
   <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <a style="font-size: 18px;" href="images/Flyer_2016.pdf" target="_blank">Download Order Form</a>
  </div>
 <p style="font-size: 14px;">
    <strong>Please fax or email the order form to the office.</strong>
 </p>
```

If the user check input id=both, the value will be 90 multiplied by option value from select id =bal_number_of_members.

Else if the user click either input id = cat-aeral and input id = cat-loto, the value wold be 50 multiplied by option value from select id = bal_number_of_members.

With this set up, if I check id=both, and option value from select id =bal_number_of_members

```
 1 = 90 //value of 90 + 3
 2 = 186.00 //93 * 2
 3 = 279.00
 4 = 372.00
 5 = 465.00
 6 = 558.00
 7 = 651.00
 8 = 744.00
 9 = 873.00
```

Our accounting officer notice this  calculation is not correct
It should be

```
 1 = 93.00 //3.00 
 2 = 185.68  // 5.68
......
```

How to correctly get total with percentage?

This is what she want

```
   Additional 2.9% + $0.30 processing fee will be charged with all orders paid by credit card.
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here to try to understand. A jsfiddle might help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of the solution [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbt1hr3o/)

```js
  function trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount() {
    var qty = jQuery('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    var current_val = jQuery("input[name=cat]:checked").val();
  //console.log(current_val);
    var amount = parseInt(qty) * current_val;
    amount = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
    return amount;
  }

  
  function trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount() {
    var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
    console.log(parseFloat(amount));
    var totalamount = parseFloat(amount)+((parseFloat(amount)*0.029)+0.30);
    console.log(totalamount);
    totalamount = parseFloat(totalamount).toFixed(2);
    console.log(totalamount);

    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=tmp_total_amount]').val(totalamount);
  }

  function submitTrainthetrainerForm() {
    var qty = jQuery('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=quantity_1]').val(qty);

    var totalAmount = 0;
    var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
    var processingFee = trainthetrainerForm_calculateFee();

    totalAmount = amount + processingFee;

    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=business]').val('shana@same.org');
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount]').val(totalAmount);
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount_2]').val(processingFee);
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form').submit();
    return true;
  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', $("#bal_number_of_members"), function() {
      trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
    });
    jQuery("#bal_submit_btn").click(function() {
      submitTrainthetrainerForm();
    });

    trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="contentheading" style="margin-top: 0px;">2016 “Train-The-Trainer” Workshops<br /><br /> AERIAL</h2>
<div>
  <p>$50.00 per class/person
    <br />Sign up for both for $90.00</p>
</div>
<div>
  <form id="paypal_submit_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/***" method="post">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" />
    <input name="upload" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input name="charset" type="hidden" value="utf8" />
    <input name="business" type="hidden" />
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
    <input name="custom" type="hidden" />
    <input name="amount" type="hidden" />
    <input name="first_name" type="hidden" />
    <input name="last_name" type="hidden" />
    <input name="address1" type="hidden" />
    <input name="city" type="hidden" />
    <input name="state" type="hidden" />
    <input name="zip" type="hidden" />
    <input name="email" type="hidden" />
    <input name="night_phone_b" type="hidden" />
    <input name="address_override" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <div id="paypal_prs" style="font-size: 12px;">
      <p>
        <input id="cat-both" checked="checked" name="cat" type="radio" value="90" />
        <label for="cat-both">Both</label>
        <input id="cat-aerial" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" />
        <label for="cat-aerial">Aerial</label>
        <input id="cat-loto" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" />
        <label for="cat-loto">Lockout/Tagout</label>
      </p>
      <br /> Members:
      <select id="bal_number_of_members" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 3px;" name="number_of_members">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
      </select>
      <br /> Total Amount (Cost + Processing Fee):
      <input style="width: 50px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 2px; padding-bottom: 1px; font-size: 12px;" name="tmp_total_amount" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="93" />
      <input id="bal_submit_btn" style="padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 12px; cursor: pointer;" type="button" value="Pay Here" />
      <input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="2016 Train-The-Trainer Workshops(AERIAL LIFTS &amp; LOCKOUT/TAGOUT)" />
      <input name="amount_1" type="hidden" value="90" />
      <input name="quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1" />
      <input name="item_name_2" type="hidden" value="Processing fee" />
      <input name="amount_2" type="hidden" value="0" />
      <input name="quantity_2" type="hidden" value="1" />
    </div>
    <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/tmp_ipn.php" />
    <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/" />
    <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/index.php?view=article&amp;id=278" />
    <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1" />
  </form>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px; color: red;">
  Additional 2.9% + $0.30 processing fee will be charged with all orders paid by credit card.
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <a style="font-size: 18px;" href="images/Flyer_2016.pdf" target="_blank">Download Order Form</a>
</div>
<p style="font-size: 14px;">
  <strong>Please fax or email the order form to the office.</strong>
</p>
```

You need to calculate the base amount first for the selected quantities and then apply above fees on that amount. For example,

If user has selected 'both' and no. of members as 2, then the base amount will be 180. Now apply the fees to this base amount, which will be 
(180*0.029)+0.30 = 5.52. So your total amount will be 185.52

what you have done in current_index appears incorrect. additional 2.9% + 0.30 should be applied to total base amount i.e. 90 (for both) * qty

Comment: your code works, but i need it only when the user select 'both', also, if I select 2 member, I want this as exactly 185.68 instead of 185.52, same if  I select member 3, it should be 278.37 instead of 278.13

Comment: you may want to recheck the calculations with your accountant. Mathematically you will get above values for 2.9% and fee of 0.30. I was able to get the values you are looking for by applying a percentage of 2.988888888888 ...working example, with latter % applied https://jsfiddle.net/vbt1hr3o/1/

Comment: with above example, you should get values of 92.999 and 185.68. if you want to restrict this calculations only for both, what cals you need to apply for other checkboxes? you can use a switch condition to alter your code accordingly

Comment: you are my saviour man.if I can upvote 100 points for, I would do it

Comment: There's one thing, when I select the cat-aerial or cat-loto, the value of "both" will be sent to paypal.It shoul be

Comment: the value of both will still sent to paypal even if I clicked the cat-aerial or the cat-loto

Comment: you need to modify submitTrainthetrainerForm function. Also in the example I shared, the value displayed in the box is with processing fees. as per the function, that should be sent to paypal additionally in the hidden field you have. The box displayed should show 90 / 180 only.

Comment: I am still struggling with this js code.I haven't found the solution for this to work.cat-both value will send to paypal even I select cat-aerial and cat-loto.I add a small function but not successfull.Please help me this $(document).on('change',$('input[name="tmp_total_amount"]'),function(){
    $('input[name="amount_1"]').val($('input[name="tmp_total_amount"]').val())
  })